# Issue with adding style to element with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and trying to add a class if a select element holds a value that I want to check against.

```
class App extends Component {
  test = 'volvo';
  render() {
    return (
      <select style={{marginTop: '30px', marginLeft: '20px'}}>
        <option value="volvo" className={test === 'volvo' ? "selected" : null}>Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

It's giving me an error where on the line here I have the ternary operator. Can someone tell me the proper way of doing this please?
Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are accessing a global variable inside the class, you have to use `this` keyword.

```
className={this.test === 'volvo' ? "selected" : null}
```

Comment: thank you! ill accept this as the correct answer when it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

In the global execution context (outside of any function), this refers to the global object. Try below code. You have to use `this` keyword.

```
class App extends Component {
test = 'volvo';
render() {
return (
  <select style={{marginTop: '30px', marginLeft: '20px'}}>
    <option value="volvo" className={this.test === 'volvo' ? "selected" : null}>Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  );
 }
}
```